# access is denied using jquery-1.4.1.js

Tags: jquery, wcf

i am using VS2010 with jquery-1.4.1.js version and i try to access the WCF service and i get a strange error **"Access is denied"** in **jquery-1.4.1.js** at page number **4982**

jquery-1.4.1.js:

```
    // Open the socket
    // Passing null username, generates a login popup on Opera (#2865)
    if ( s.username ) {
        xhr.open(type, s.url, s.async, s.username, s.password);
    } else {
        xhr.open(type, s.url, s.async);
    }
```

**here is how i am calling**

```
 function PostData() {           

        var webMethod = 'http://myservices/SomeService.svc/GetCount'
        var parameters = "{'Id': '" + "1" + "'}"
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webMethod,
            data: parameters,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                //$(divToBeWorkedOn).html(msg.d);
                debugger
            },
            error: function (e) {
                //$(divToBeWorkedOn).html("Unavailable");
            }
        });
    }
```

what might be the problem? i test my wcf service and it works fine, i try connecting through asp.net and add web reference just to see if there is any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is unnecessary:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
```

It tells the server what kind of data you are sending, not what you expect to receive, and you aren't actually sending any data.

---

**Edit**

It seems that you are calling a script on another domain.  This violates the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript): you can only make AJAX requests to items on the same domain.  There is a workaround using something called JSONP, which requires server-side support. See the documentation for `$.ajax`, especially the [JSONP dataType section](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

Comment: i have update my question, i am sending some parameters and its depend on what method i am using, some methods accepts more than once and some accepts only one parameters.